# 过道/走廊 what's the difference?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

It seems to me that these two are pretty interchangeable for 'hallway' - at least in the writing I've read before.

My question is, though, is there any difference in meaning?

Any difference when to use one over the other?!

Comment: If it's inside a building, such as a corridor, it is more often called 过道. I would call the passage in a train carriage 过道 as well but this is perhaps a matter of individual preference. 走廊 is usually applied to more formal / artistic things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For buildings, according to [住宅设计规范(Design code for residential buildings) GB50096-2011](http://baike.baidu.com/view/2683768.htm?fr=aladdin#4_3),

> 2．0．13 过道 passage
> 　　住宅套内使用的水平通道。
>
> 2．0．20 走廊 gallery
> 　　住宅套外使用的水平通道。

So the internal transport space, such as the passageway inside the cinema or train, can be said as "过道".

And the transport space which is outside the building, independent, covered, can be said as "走廊".

Except for buildings, "走廊" can also be used for a narrow strip(corridor) connects two areas. Such as "河西走廊".

Answer (score 1):

过道 means a passageway that could be either passed through by transportation such as cars or bikes, or by pedestrian. 过道 is more used in a open space.

走廊 is the word for "hallway."  As the word 走（walk）suggests, it is usually used to mean a passageway in a build that could be walked through.

Note that 走道 also means passageway or aisle that could only be passed through by pedestrian as the word 走（walk）suggests.